# For loop optimisation

Tags: c++

Here are some variations of for loops:

1) Standard:

```
for (int i=0; i<limit; i++)
```

2) Using preincrement

```
for (int i=0; i<limit; ++i)
```

3) Inverting the loop

```
for (int i=limit-1; i>=0; i--)
```

4) Using preincrement in the test

```
for (int i=0; ++i<=limit; )
```

5) Mixing 3 and 4

```
for (int i=limit; --i>=0; )
```

So, my question is, should number 5 be used in the majority of cases? It seems highly optimised, but I am wary of gotchas.
Could someone please shed some light onto what the compiler will do in these situations?
Also, what will happen if i is an iterator, not an int? Or if i is unsigned?
I am specifically interested in C++, but if there are differences with other languages, that would be highly interesting too.
Thanks

Comment: This is a question for Stackoverflow.com. It's not gamedev related.

Comment: Ah I see. Sorry. Is it possible to move it then?

Comment: The only worthwhile optimization here is to use `var` instead of `int` as the variable declarator, if available. This instructs the compiler to ensure that the loop counter is the native machine size, enabling it to be a register variable. At that point, all of the forms you describe are native register commands of equal performance.

Comment: You're wasting your time. None of these cases are likely to ever make a measurable difference, and if they ever do (through use of a profiler), they should be trivial to change.

Comment: @DaleyPaley You can ask a moderator to move it.

Comment: I personally like for (into i = 0, len = […]; i < len; i++)

Comment: @stephelton Indeed, but note that a reversed iteration order may have significant secondary effects on memory accesses done by the body.

Answer (score 5):

As much as I agree that preincrementing is intuitively faster (because the implementation does not involve a copy), I would expect the compiler to actually optimize both calls to become equivalent in a case where there is no ambiguity like that (preincrementing or postincrementing is irrelevant in the calculation).

Furthermore, I sincerely doubt that the for loop itself will become your bottleneck in a game. If you ask such a question because you notice performance problems in your project, then I would advise you to use a profiler (such as VerySleepy for C++) which will explicitly tell you where your program spends most of its time.

After that, you can try and optimize the code that really matters.

By spending time searching for small optimizations like that which will probably not bring any difference to the execution time (because it is not a bottleneck of your application), you are essentially wasting time that you could be spending optimizing bottlenecks. Which brings me back to saying this: *optimize your schedule before your code; profile first, optimize after.*

This being said, I assume that you are just asking this question by curiosity and wondering which one is faster. If this is what you seek, then your question would be more appropriate on StackOverflow, because it is not specifically related to optimization in game development.

Comment: I agree - they all compile to about the same thing, especially in terms of performance relative to other things that the application will be doing. I do think that more import than writhing the absolute fastest possible for loop is writing clean code that any programmer in the team can very quickly and intuitively understand.

Comment: I really appreciate all the replies, and yes, in most cases the loop computation will be negligible, but I would still like an answer to the question, about how they will compile and how they compare. There are cases in extremely tight nested loops, and on some very limited hardware such as old 8-bit systems where it may still be important.

Comment: @DaleyPaley If you are interested, why not simply compile each example and read the assembly code? I don't see why another person's experience is required to answer a question a machine is perfectly able to produce an answer for?